# Cannot add properties to jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I should be able to see a yellow square appear on my screen every 5000 milliseconds, but I don't.

The `squareGenerator()` function creates a square with the properties specified, but I don't see it.

Please take a look at my JavaScript, thanks.

```js
//Square Generation
var allSquares = [];
var idGenerated = 0;

function squareGenerator() {

  var newSquare = $(document.createElement("div"));
  newSquare.attr('id', idGenerated);

  $("#" + idGenerated).css({
    "background-color": "yellow",
    "height": "200px",
    "width": "200px",
    "position": "absolute"
  });

  $('.father').append(newSquare);

  allSquares.push(newSquare);
  idGenerated++;
}

var squareGenerationInterval = setInterval(squareGenerator, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.father {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NovaNote</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="father">

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="function.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: no, the bug is `$('.father').append(newSquare);` should be above the `$("#" + idGenerated)` line as you not put it on the dom yet.

Comment: Why are you selecting the element when you already have it? `newSquare.css({...`

Comment: what @epascarello really meant is `$(newSquare).css({...`

Comment: @epascarello that is so that I can then change each square's margin css property without being affected by the other squares' margin css before they are even created by the square generator.

Comment: @WiseEye it is the SAME element you are trying to select..... If your theory was correct, setting the id would not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use jQuery's `$` to select an element, it will only select elements that currently exist in the DOM. Since you only append the `newSquare` at the *end* of `squareGenerator`, the newly created element is only selectable via jQuery *after* that point.

You can either append the element before (move up `$('.father').append(newSquare);`) - or, even better - you already have a reference to the new element when you do `var newSquare = $(document.createElement("div"));`, so just reference `newSquare` again instead of trying to select it again:

```js
//Square Generation
var allSquares = [];
var idGenerated = 0;

function squareGenerator() {

  var newSquare = $(document.createElement("div"));
  newSquare.attr('id', idGenerated);

  newSquare.css({
    "background-color": "yellow",
    "height": "200px",
    "width": "200px",
    "position": "absolute"
  });
  
  $('.father').append(newSquare);
  allSquares.push(newSquare);
  idGenerated++;
}

var squareGenerationInterval = setInterval(squareGenerator, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.father {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NovaNote</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="father">

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="function.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Or, much more concisely:

```js
//Square Generation
var allSquares = [];

function squareGenerator() {
  var newSquare = $('<div />')
    .css({
      "background-color": "yellow",
      "height": "200px",
      "width": "200px",
      "position": "absolute"
    })
    .appendTo('.father');
  allSquares.push(newSquare);
}

var squareGenerationInterval = setInterval(squareGenerator, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.father {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="father">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference `$("#" + idGenerated)` before the element get to the DOM tree. move the `.append` statement prior to it and it should work

```js
//Square Generation
var allSquares = [];
var idGenerated = 0;

function squareGenerator() {

  var newSquare = $(document.createElement("div"));
  newSquare.attr('id', idGenerated);

  $('.father').append(newSquare);

  $("#" + idGenerated).css({
    "background-color": "yellow",
    "height": "200px",
    "width": "200px",
    "position": "absolute"
  });


  allSquares.push(newSquare);
  idGenerated++;
}

var squareGenerationInterval = setInterval(squareGenerator, 500);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.father {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NovaNote</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="father">

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="function.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```